# Find first common parent for multiple children from mixed hierarchy levels

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, tree, recursive-query

Find the first common parent, if any, from many different children.

Example:

```
    1       
   / \     
  2   3    
 /   / \
7   8   9  
   / \
 10   11
```

Input: [10, 9]
Output: 3 (first common parent for this elements)

Table example:

```
+------------------+-----------+------+
|EmployeePositionId|Subdivision|Parent|
+------------------+-----------+------+
|4718              |485        |42    |
|4719              |5064       |485   |
|4720              |5065       |5064  |
|4721              |5065       |5064  |
|4722              |3000       |null  |
+------------------+-----------+------+
```

If I try to search for `EmployeePositionId` [4719, 4720, 4721],
I would like to get the `Subdivision` 5064, because it is the closest common subdivision for both employees (5065 nested in 5064).

If I were looking for 4719, 4720, 4721, 4722, then I would like to get null, because these elements do not have a common parent.

Or the answer will help me how get the data so that later solve this in Python

Comment: Based on what logic? Please, be more specific and provide more details.

Comment: Is there an indicator for the level of hierarchy in the table? And is the integrity of the tree guaranteed (no loops)? Min / max number of input IDs? All input IDs exist in the table? Your Postgres version?

Comment: I found this, but it is only looking at two ids, not a variable number. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608076/how-to-get-lowest-common-parent-for-2-rows-in-recursive-table-sql

Comment: – Maciej Los, it is necessary to find the closest general department by employees, if any

Comment: – Erwin Brandstetter, there is no hierarchy indicator in the table, but you can add it in the query in the non-recursive part: 0 as "level" if it helps. There are definitely no cycles. This tree is "up". Min input - 0, Max - not more than 1500. All input IDs exist in the table. Postgres 10.11

Answer (score 1):

This class of problems is ***hard*** for SQL.
It's even harder with your particular table. It's not properly normalized. There is no level indicator. And input IDs can be from mixed hierarchy levels.

#### Setup

You clarified in a later comment that every path is terminated with a row that has `"Parent" IS NULL` (root), even if sample data in the question suggest otherwise. That helps a bit.

I assume valid "EmployeePositionId" as input. And no loops in your tree or the CTE enters an endless loop.

If you don't have a level of hierarchy in the table, add it. It's a simple task. If you can't add it, create a `VIEW` or, preferably, a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html) instead:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_tbl AS
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT *, 0 AS level
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  "Parent" IS NULL
   
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.*, c.level + 1
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   tbl t ON t."Parent" = c."Subdivision"
   )
TABLE cte;
```

These would be the perfect indices for the task:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mv_tbl_id_uni ON mv_tbl ("EmployeePositionId") INCLUDE ("Subdivision", "Parent", level);  
CREATE INDEX mv_tbl_subdivision_idx ON mv_tbl ("Subdivision") INCLUDE ("Parent", level);
```

See:

- [Covering index for top read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207938/3684)

#### Query

Pure SQL solution with recursive CTE, based on a table with level indicator (or the MV from above):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE init AS (
   SELECT "Subdivision", "Parent", level
   FROM   mv_tbl
   WHERE  "EmployeePositionId" IN (4719, 4720, 4721)  -- input
   )
, cte AS (
   TABLE init
   UNION
   SELECT c."Parent", t."Parent", c.level - 1
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   mv_tbl t ON t."Subdivision" = c."Parent"  -- recursion terminated at "Parent" IS NULL
   )
, agg AS (
   SELECT level, min("Subdivision") AS "Subdivision", count(*) AS ct
   FROM   cte
   GROUP  BY  level
   )
SELECT "Subdivision"
FROM   agg a
WHERE  ct = 1                                  -- no other live branch
AND    level <  (SELECT max(level) FROM cte WHERE "Parent" IS NULL) IS NOT TRUE  -- no earlier dead end
AND    level <= (SELECT min(level) FROM init)  -- include highest (least) level
ORDER  BY level DESC                           -- pick earliest (greatest) qualifying level
LIMIT  1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e05768d300fba7d3710de3c84d7d4cad)*

Covers all possible input, works for any modern version of Postgres.

I added basic explanation in the code.

Related:

- [How to aggregate a table with tree-structure to a single nested JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280978/how-to-aggregate-a-table-with-tree-structure-to-a-single-nested-json-object/62288599#62288599)
- [How to turn a set of flat trees into a single tree with multiple leaves?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294044/3684)

Legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers make your life with Postgres easier. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: For `{4719, 4720, 4721, 4722}` your query returns `42` instead of null.

Comment: @MaciejLos: Consider the improved query.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no nesting level in the table. And I cannot add the constraint "Parent not null". "Parent = null" indicates that the unit is at the root. This is how a huge table is arranged and works, I cannot make such changes to it. But can solve the problem like this - tell me please how to get the data in such a way that i can solve the problem in post-processing in Python

Comment: @Masta I didn't suggest a constraint "Parent not null". Consider updates for your added information (which should be in the question). Good luck.